# Pattern for Primefaces inputMask

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want implement a inputField with maxChars=100 and only A-Z, a-z can be inputted. Is this possible with the PrimeFaces inputMask?

I use JSF 2.1 and PrimeFaces 4.0.

```
<p:inputMask style="width:350px" id="lastname" value="#{regiBean.user.LAST_NAME}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_lastname_error']}" maxlength="5" mask="a"   placeHolder="_" />
```

Comment: did you see here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csvCustom.jsf

Comment: yes but i want that only  a-z can be input other things should be blocked

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. And change better in your "User" Java Class the property geter from LAST_NAME to getLastName()

```
<p:inputMask style="width:350px" id="lastname" value="#{regiBean.user.LAST_NAME}" required="true" 
requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_lastname_error']}" maxlength="100" mask="a*"   placeHolder="_" />
```

Comment: I already try this , the problem is that * stand for Charachters